# Webdev IDE and Remote Development with large codebase

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, lamp, remote-debugging

So I'm doing LAMP/PHP development in-house on a machine with Netbeans IDE.  The codebase and database is on this machine.  However, I also am doing remote development over VPN/SSH as well.

I've tried using NetBeans on my laptop from home using the "existing remote sources" feature.  However, it takes a ridiculously long amount of time to download the large codebase, and it is also taking equally as long synchronizing the files (which has the potential to fail pretty badly).

It's also not too quick to subversion my code between the remote (in-house) machine and the local laptop. It would mean I would have to git commit, push, do a pull on the remote machine, fix conflicts potentially, and then be able to refresh the remote page to see the changes.  That's just not a quick enough turnaround.

Are there any alternatives I can use?  I tried Komodo IDE, but it doesn't have a decent autocomplete ability like Netbeans since it doesn't copy the codebase over locally.

Or, has anyone come up with a technique that has worked out for them?

Comment: You've tagged the question as "remote-debugging". Do you really need to run the code on another machine than the one you're working on? Otherwise, that is exactly what source-control systems are for. Subversion and Git only synchronize the code that has changed since it was last updated, making bandwith basically a non-issue, except for the first checkout.

Comment: @PMF So, what you're saying is that I should make a repository on the on-site machine, and just synchronize that way?  I'd have to save, commit, push, and test the site remotely each time.

Comment: @PMF in other words, yes that's what i'm doing, remote-debugging.

Comment: You did not write that you're doing web-page development. I'm not so familiar with that. You could just run the debugger on the remote machine and use vnc or something similar to control it. May be faster than downloading the code. Or you have the code run on your local system while you're testing it.

Comment: @PMF yea, i oddly couldn't find a tag for web development.  Tagging what I can that is relevant.